# How to simulate combination for concurrent and ramp load in karate gatling

Tags: karate

My requirement is to set up a load a load for 1 hour as below -

```
start from rampup user 0 to 140 in 5 mins 
then concurrent user 140 for 30 mins 
then again rampup user 140-160 for 15 mins 
then again concurrent user 160 for 10 mins.
```

For this I gave scala file as below -

```
package features.Performance
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class PerfTests extends Simulation {

  before {
    println("Perf tests started")
  }

  val getTest1 = scenario("Performance test for ramp user(0 to 140)").exec(karateFeature("classpath:features/Performance/Perf.feature"))
  val getTest2 = scenario("Performance test for concurrent users 140").exec(karateFeature("classpath:features/Performance/Perf.feature"))
  val getTest3 = scenario("Performance test for ramp user(140 to 160)").exec(karateFeature("classpath:features/Performance/Perf.feature"))
  val getTest4 = scenario("Performance test for concurrent users 160").exec(karateFeature("classpath:features/Performance/Perf.feature"))

  setUp (    
    getTest1.inject(rampUsersPerSec(0) to (140) during( 5 minutes)),
    getTest2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(140).during(30 minutes)),
    getTest3.inject(rampUsersPerSec(140) to (160) during( 15 minutes)),
    getTest4.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(160).during(10 minutes))
    
  ).assertions(
    global.responseTime.max.lt(10000))

  after {
    println("Perf tests ended")
  }
}
```

Perf.feature has a simple Post request.

Is this correct way of doing it or there is better way to simulate this load?

Kind Regards,

Neha

Comment: Your current implementation is correct and should work for the load simulation you described. However, you can improve the code readability and maintainability by using a more concise approach for setting up the load test scenarios like Gatling's injection methods, which allows you to chain multiple injection steps together.